# How to organize massive spreadsheet, while retaining any important information in duplicates?

Tags: excel, database, duplicates, data-cleaning

We have a massive Excel spreadsheet of contact info (name, email, phone, notes, etc...), 30,000+ rows, and it's riddled with typos, duplicates, and many other inconsistencies. We're trying to merge this database with another very messy, 30,000+ row database which has significant overlap (~75%) in data between the first sheet. We're trying to organize all of the data so that we can move all of our contact info into a new software.

The fields of the spreadsheet look like this

Columns:

> Location, Email, First Name, Last Name, Phone #1, Address, etc..

There are a lot of obstacles when trying to merge. I'm sure there are loads more, but here are some off the top of my head

1. There are tons of duplicates, but I can't do a simple "remove duplicates" Say Row X some is duplicate in 5/6 fields, but contains important info in the 6th that I don't want to discard, nor dedicate an entire row to. Is there a way to remove duplicates and then merge the reduced row with the unique info from Row X to create one row? (I hope that makes sense)
2. One client may have multiple emails/location, is there a way to group this info under one Last name instead of having multiple rows?
3. Typos/human error mistakes (duplicates with slight typos, John Smiht instead of John Smith) that Excel won't read as duplicates.

there are many other issues, but these are the big three to come to mind. If anyone has any advice on how to approach this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You've got a lot of work ahead of you.  You can write some minor tools to help with some of this, but ultimately it's going to take eyes on the data to resolve some of the issues you've identified

Answer (score 0):

Here are my tips.

1. Organize your Headings.
2. Arrange your two workbooks with the same headings. if necessary insert blank columns and rename them according to desired headings
3. Merge your two workbooks.
4. In your 3rd Workbook insert one column at the beginning name the column as Full Name. and Merge the Last Name, First Name and Middle Name.
5. Copy and paste it as Values
6. Sort Your Sheet1 per Full Name
7. Copy your Sheet1 on your Sheet2 Delete Duplicates using Full Name or First Column.
8. Use Index-Match or Vlookup to find other Data.

9.Now to Avoid Blanks Or Empty Cells. You can Segregate Sheet1 into multiple Sheets and SOrt it base on Z to A. Like
When you need to find the Address Data of Name Alfred since theres so many same Alfred FULL Name in Sheet1 you copy FullName COlumn And Address Column to Sheet3 and sort by COlumn A and B.
In your Sheet2 you can do Index-Match and Vlookup since it will find the first row that matches your Unique Data.

Lastly You can Avoid this If you use MS-Access in the future.